# Tor is a covariant functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, functors, derived-functors

Various books and many online notes and other posts such as [Proving that $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R$ is a bifunctor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883232/proving-that-operatornametor-nr-is-a-bifunctor) give a rather touch-and-go treatment to Tor being a covariant functor. For example, in Matsumara's Commutative Ring Theory, Appendix B, the treatment for Tor is very brief with only the outline of how Tor is constructed. I am currently stuck on the claim that Tor is a covariant functor.

The following definition is from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra that I am working with (commutative rings throughout).

> If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are categories, we say that $\mathcal{F}$ is a covariant functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ if:
>
> (1) for every object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{F}A$ is an object in $\mathcal{D}$
>
> (2) for every morphism $f\in Mor_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$, we have $\mathcal{F}f\in Mor_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathcal{F}A,\mathcal{F}B)$
>
> such that $\mathcal{F}(1_{A})=1_{\mathcal{F}A}$ and if $g\circ f$ is a composition of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{F}(gf)=\mathcal{F}(g)\mathcal{F}(f)$.

The definition of Tor that I am working with is from Matsumara's Commutative Ring Theory Appendix B:

In brief, the construction starts with two projective resolutions of $A$-modules $M$ and $N$, given by $P_{\bullet}$ and $Q_{\bullet}$ respectively, which after taking $M\otimes_{A}-$ and $-\otimes_{A}N$ respectively, we get two complexes $P_{\bullet}\otimes_{A}N$ and $M\otimes_{A}Q_{\bullet}$. Then we define $\mathrm{Tor}_{n}^{A}(M,N)\cong H_{n}(M\otimes_{A}Q_{\bullet})\cong H_{n}(P_{\bullet}\otimes_{A}N)$, where $H_{n}(K_{\bullet})$ is the $n$-th homology of the complex $K_{\bullet}$.

Most online notes are brief and simply outlines why Tor is a covariant functor. However I am having trouble figuring out the respective maps to show that Tor is indeed a covariant functor, getting lost in the many commutative diagrams.

My knowledge on homological algebra is highly elementary and introductory. However I would appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: Are you lost in proving it is a functor or proving that it is covariant?

Comment: @Randall: The definition (in Dummit and Foote) I am working with refers to (ordinary) functors as covariant functors. So in that sense of your comment, it would be (both) functoriality and covariance.

Comment: The functoriality essentially comes down to the functoriality of all the little intermediate steps:  tensor product is a functor, and forming homology is a functor, so compose them and the result is a functor.  I guess you need to throw in some projective resolution well-defined stuff, but that's about it.

Comment: @Randall I am able to understand that $-\otimes_{A}M$ for any module $M$ is a right exact functor. However, are you able to provide any references that would allow me to better understand that Homology is a functor and hence composition of that with the tensor would give the Tor and hence would mean that Tor is a covariant functor?

Comment: For homological stuff Weibel's book is pretty quick and readable.  Details will have to be filled in yourself, as no one really lays out all details of all proofs at this stage of the game.